# Quadratic Functions - vertex of graph proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

[image]

Can you explain how $x$ becomes $x + b/2a$ and $c$ becomes $4ac - b^2/4a$ all of sudden?

Can you please explain at a Pre-Calculus level, thank you very much.

Comment: If you expand $\left(x+\frac ba\right)^2$, and multiply through and add back the constant, you’ll get the original expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This technique is called [completing the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square).

Comment: Would this not work better as a comment?

Comment: Yeah. That's a respectable position. At one point I had that attitude. but alot of these PSQs get answered in the comments and then never actually answered. My thinking on this issue has changed. I think that if you give an answer (even if it's a hint) you should put it as an answer. And I reserve the right to change my thinking on this.

Comment: $$y=ax^2+bx+c$$ $$y/a=x^2+\frac{b}ax+\frac{c}a$$ $$y/a=x^2+\frac{b}ax+\frac{b^2}{4a^2}-\frac{b^2}{4a^2}+\frac{c}a$$ $$y/a=(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2+\frac{c}a-\frac{b^2}{4a^2}$$ $$y/a=(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2+\frac{4ac}{4a^2}-\frac{b^2}{4a^2}$$ $$y/a=\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2+\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a^2}$$ $$y=a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2+\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}$$